# Android 2.2 or 4.1?

Tags: android

When creating my new app should I build against 2.2 or 4.1? I know 2.2 has 83% of the market right now but can I build against 4.1 and make the min sdk android 2.0?

Comment: yes, set your min sdk to 2.0, and your target to 4.x

Comment: Correction: 63,6% are on 2.3.3. Source: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Set the minimum, maximum and target SDK in AndroidManifest.xml like :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:maxSdkVersion="16"
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: I would recommend not setting a maxSdkVerion at all costs. It makes the app not available on the Play store over that SDK version, so unless there is a reason you want this don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your build target should alway be latest platform (i.e. Jelly Bean API 16). Properties->Android->Build target

In your manifest you should define something like:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Lint will tell you if your code uses something not available in previous versions.  You can test you code on any emulator to ensure correct functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so, but there are some features that aren't available on the previous android versions. Before using them make sure to check for the OS version like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
 // only for android older than gingerbread
}
```